# SQL server state management on a 3-tiered architecture

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Folks,

Has anyone came across a scenario where they have used SQL server state management on a 3 tiered architectuere ?

How should one implement (SQL server state management) without bypassing the middlelayer.

Thanks...

Comment: Beyond the yes or no version, what is the actual question here?

Comment: What is your concern regarding bypassing the middle layer? SQL Server state management is essentially a service that solves a application-layer problem. Why should it participate in your middle layer at all?

Comment: In our scenario: we have

Web Server (neutral zone) --> App server (semi-trusted zone) --> DB (full trusted zone)

DB will not take any request other than comming from APP Server.
If I have to implement the SQL State then essentially I would be accessgint the DB from the WEB Server, which would not work in UAT/PRO Enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, If the client is too strong on the 3 tier requirement and if the Web server(s) cannont talk with DB directly then StateServer is the solution.